# How to fix "no implicit conversion of String into Hash"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I am trying to run a test with RSpec but it always returns the same error:

```
DevicesController#update when user is a manager must update any device
     Failure/Error: put device_path device_id, params: params, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json' }

     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of String into Hash
```

My function with the request params:

```
def update_params(device, device_id)
  {
    data: {
      id: device.id,
      type: 'device',
      attributes: {
        device_id: device_id 
      }
    }
  }.to_json
end
```

My test using factories:

```
context 'when user is a manager' do
  let(:user) { create(:manager).account }
  let(:firebase_token) { Faker::Crypto.sha1 }
  let(:device_id) { physical_device.id }
  let(:params) { update_params(physical_device, firebase_token) }
  it 'must update any device' do
    expect(Device.find(device_id).device_id).to eq(firebase_token)
  end
end
```

The request OS update device:

```
put device_path device_id, params: params, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json' }
```

Comment: Try wrapping the `device_id` within the `device_path` method (`device_path(device_id)`).

Comment: remove the ` .to_json` in update_params.  That's turning your parameters hash into a string of json

Comment: I use the same body request with to_json for create method and this error dnt ocurred, dsnt make sense

Comment: Yeah, i've try with put(device_path(device_id)...) but server return me 400 - Bad request

Answer (score 0):

[ActionController::TestCase](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html) expects the `params` to be a hash (like the `headers`).

But the `params` you pass to this method call

```
put device_path device_id, params: params, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json' }
```

are generated by the `update_params` method and that method calls `to_json` on the generated hash and therefore returns a JSON *string*.

Just remove the `.to_json` from the last line of the `update_params` method and you should be fine.

Comment: Great. That means that your test request works! Problem solved. But unfortunately your app is not able to handle the `application/vnd.api+json` mime-type. Did you register that mime-type in your Rails application – for example by following this [article](https://blog.codeship.com/the-json-api-spec/)? Because this is actually a different problem you might want to open a new question if the link doesn't solve that issue.